# How do I automatically add a class variable to certain subclasses

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class A(object):
    _all = set()

    def __new__(cls):
        obj = super(A,cls).__new__(cls)
        cls._all.add(obj)
        return obj

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass

b = B()
c = C()
```

This will create all instances and put them in `A._all`. What I want is for the instances of `C` to be placed in `C._all` (and similarly for C).

I could define `B` and `C` like this:

```
class B(A):
    _all = set()

class C(A):
    _all = set()
```

Which would work. However, this feels like repeating code, and if I forget to add `_all` when I subclass `A` next, or misspell `_alll` I'm likely to get hard to debug errors.

How would I go about doing this well?

Comment: Should not it be `cls._all.add(obj)` instead of `cls._all.add(cls)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a metaclass for it:

```
class make_all_meta(type):
   def __init__(cls, name, bases, dic):
       type.__init__(cls, name, bases, dic)
       cls._all = set()

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = make_all_meta
```

In Python 3, the definition for `A` must be:

```
class A(metaclass=make_all_meta):
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

Set `_all` to `None` and create your set in `__new__` if still `None`, to give each class it's own copy:

```
class A(object):
    _all = None

    def __new__(cls):
        obj = super(A,cls).__new__(cls)
        if cls._all is None:
            cls._all = set()
        cls._all.add(cls)
        return obj
```

Comment: Exactly the approach I was going to suggest. You could also do it with a metaclass, although that's slightly more complicated.

Comment: The metaclass way feels more "correct", but I'm worried about further complications down the line.

Comment: Also, I would not be able to do things like `len(B._all)==0` because until at least one `B` is instantiated, `B._all is None`

Comment: I've posted an answer with a metaclass. You're right that it does simplify the `len()` issue. Of course, you could also just initially define `_all` as an empty tuple or something instead of `None`.

Comment: This solution assumes that there will be no instances of A created before first instances of all other subclasses. I would suggest at least doing `assert cls is not A` in `__new__`.

Comment: Another possible solution is using `_all=set()` in `A` and `if cls is not A and cls._all is A._all: cls._all=set()` in `__new__`, but this is still subject to `len(B._all)` problem.